# Can't use stringified JSON in graphene test

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene2

I'm trying to write a test that takes in a stringified json value for one of my fields (questionData) and it's failing:

I wrote the mutation like this:

```
        query = '''mutation {
            createScorecard(
                name: "Test Scorecard",
                creatorId: 395549257913,
                questionData: "[{\"title\":\"This is a test question\",\"description\":\"Test question description\",\"answers\":[{\"text\":\"Yes\",\"point\":50,\"autofail\":true},{\"text\":\"No\",\"point\":50,\"autofail\":false}]}]"
            ) {
                scorecard {
                    name
                }
                error
            }
        }'''
```

But i keep getting this error:

> {'errors': [{'message': 'Syntax Error GraphQL (5:40) Expected :, found String ":"\n\n4:                 creatorId: 395549257913,\n5:                 questionData: "[{"title":"This is a test question","description":"Test question description","answers":[{"text":"Yes","point":50,"autofail":true},{"text":"No","point":50,"autofail":false}]}]"\n                                          ^\n6:             ) {\n', 'locations': [{'line': 5, 'column': 40}]}]}

Comment: What you are showing us is not JSON.

Comment: questionData? It's stringified. I'll update OP to be more clear

Comment: It looks like you're passing the wrong data in an API call.  But we have no idea what API you're calling or what data it expects, so we'll need a lot more detail.

Comment: Sorry updated OP. QuestionData is expecting a string. I have a JSON result I've stringified and escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use double backslashes when escaping the string

https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/521